# Non-singular circles

Tags: geometry

In my programming coursework, to cut it short, I end up with an array of circles. We are to set a variable "circleCounter" to be the number of non-singular circles.

I'm not sure what they mean by non-singular circles, my assumption is that it means unique circles, or circles that do not have a radius of 0, but I am not entirely sure about this.

Thanks for any insight on this.

Comment: I'd bet on circles which have a radius $>0$.

Comment: Circles which do not have radius $0$ should be called "non-degenerate". Non-singular sounds like matrices.